# Can you identify this bike/frame?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image][image]

Hello  though this might be a good place to ask this.anyone knows this bike?

Comment: What are the words on the side of the downtube?  I see "46" on the second photo, but there's some white-on-chrome that is hard to see against the sky reflection.

Comment: Its just some random sticker

Comment: I'd peel it off and go with the plain chrome look personally.  Or get some decals made that say whatever you want.. "Mist's Marvellous Moving Machine" for example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ross Piranha 1986

This is my best option based on the standing platform the fork and chain stays.

[image]

http://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/ross/89509

Comment: Definitely it! Thank you very much. Know how much it is worth?

Comment: I have no idea, it's not in mint condition, it doesn't have original parts, also I don't think it was ever a very sought after or popular frame to begin with.

Comment: Most of our "identify this BMX" question go unanswered because they're so hard.  Plus the trend of stripping all decals makes it doubly hard.  Well done for finding a good answer.

Comment: Stunning! BSE managed to actually identify an old decal-less BMX! Now I suppose we'll get more of these :(

Comment: as long as they have enough distinctive features like this one I should be able to find the bike. however once the box stores started selling Chinese frames its all meaningless

Comment: I had a former ebike with chainstays like this, but they stopped at the seat post.  This would be horrible to ride with the frame touching the inside of your knee/thigh.    On the flip side, this "bumper" would protect the saddle from falls, and the frame-mounted pegs suggest its a real trick bike for doing grinds and so on.   I'd expect the bike to have a detangler for the rear brake, and a potts mod for the front brake.