# Help identify this make model of this BMX?

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage, bmx

I found this poor old bike in need of some TLC , when I moved into my new house she was just sitting out in the elements for who knows how long . Is there any saving it or should I let it go to the BMX graveyard in the sky ?
[image]

Comment: looks like scrap to me

Comment: That curve is distinctive - at the seattube/toptube/seatstays interface.  I swear we've had that here in the past in another question.

Comment: It's a classical bike from the era.  Never was all that valuable, but was loved by many kids.

Comment: I've edited out "valuation" because they're considered off topic.  Steel is about 5c/kilogram in scrap.   Resale value in your area at this time can be found via ebay etc.  Its worth whatever someone is prepared to pay for it.

Comment: I've spent time searching and cannot find a match, must have been mistaken about a prior question.  There are vaguely similar ones like https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/51623/  but they're not the same at all.

Comment: I'll bet a dollar there is at least one logo stamped on the frame - please look and post a picture.

Comment: I would like to take David D's $1.00 bet. Because all "box bikes," meaning chain retailer stores or Kent, Next, Schwinn, Mongoose and any other name brand bikes for sale at your local Walmart, do not have ANY stamps in their frames!

Answer (score 2):

It can be fixed.
You will spend multiple times it's value in time and parts to repair it.

It just depends on how much you love it.

Answer (score 0):

Rear triangle looks like GT to me, but vintage GT frames *tended* to have parallel top tube and down-tube connections at the head tube. Perhaps that changed in later generations. Googling for vintage 80s GT frames like the Performer or the Pro Performer might give you something to compare to.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be ether a old-school Redline or old-school mongoose or old-school GT

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  You could improve your answer by including some photos of the bikes you mention for comparison purposes.

Comment: Agree, can you offer up some item of identification that would qualify your answer?  SE sites do not function like a traditional forum. Documentation in answers are welcome.