# Cannot ID this bike

Tags: frames, bmx

I cannot identify this bike. I am seeking help from the group. I got this bike in 1977 so it is at least that old. Thanks
My photos won't load, I keep getting error message when adding pics.

[image]

I have more pictures but cannot load them. I get error message.

Comment: Welcome. We are going to need a little more than a year. In fact, a lot more.

Comment: What do you mean by "this bike"??  There's no picture, no description.

Comment: Welcome to the site - we need at least some detail to go on more than the year you acquired it.  Please use [edit] to add in some clear and well-lit photos of a clean bike.   More info on "how to ask a good ID-my-bike question" at https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question    As it stands this post is at risk of being closed, if it is then edit in your photos and we can go further.

Comment: Another unidentifiable bmx?

Comment: If you are getting a message and need some help with that, you have to tell us what kind of error message it is and what exactly you were trying to do.

Comment: Since you're having trouble uploading the photo here, you could host it somewhere else (imgur, Google Photos, iPhoto, etc) and then share a link to it here. It's not ideal, but it would give us something to go from. If you upload a photo or copy in a link, your post will automatically be tagged for reopening.

Comment: OK, I will try what you say.

Comment: It would really make better sense to link a picture of the whole bike. The frame number is irrelevant. See https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-serial-number/ and even https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52060/why-shouldnt-i-care-what-model-make-year-my-bicycle-is?noredirect=1&lq=1 but especially the first link. The photo of the whole bike is what is important. I am somewhat surprised that the question was just reopened with this kind of photo.

Answer (score 0):

Your photo shows a track end, so that suggests your bike has not got a derailleur for gears.

Therefore it is a single speed bike.  I cannot see an internally geared hub.

Trackends suggest it could be a track bike, but the wheel rim is in shot and it looks like a 20 inch wheel.  Therefore you probably have a BMX.

The rear wheel mount plates are welded to a single-piece curved tube that forms both the chainstay and the seat stay.   This looks similar to a Pirhana or Fuji from the `70s -   see [This Question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/51623/can-you-identify-this-bike-frame) for a similar shape.

[image] From  [Can you identify this bike/frame?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/51623/can-you-identify-this-bike-frame)